# When are the eigenvalues of the second fundamental form equal to the principal curvatures?

Tags: differential-geometry

I am confused about the following concerning the second fundamental form.
Consider a surface $S$ $\subset R^3$
If we consider a chart at a point $p \in S$, $f$: $R^2$$\to S$  and suppose $\partial f/\partial x$ and $\partial f/\partial y$ are orthonormal, Does it then follow that the eigenvalues of the second fundamental form are the principal curvatures and the eigenvectors are the principal directions?
Moreover If  $\partial f/\partial x$ and $\partial f/\partial y$ are not orthonormal this may not be true?
Thanks in advance

Comment: The second fundamental form depends only on the geometry of the surface, not on a choice of coordinates. As you say, its eigenvalues are the principal curvatures and its eigenvectors the principal directions.

If that's not what you're asking, could you please explain the purported dependence on the coordinate vectors of a parametrization?

Comment: Well I found two exersices on the second fundamental form in the first exersice the solution evaluated the second fundamental form using some chart without orthonormal derivatives and got a diagonal matrix therefore the diahgonal entries were the eigenvalues but eventually it turned out that those eigenvalues were not the principal curvatures. However the second exersice I found evaluated the second fundamental form using one chart with orthonormal derivatives and then claimed that the eigenvalues of the second fundamental form are the principal curvatures. That why I am confused

Comment: Something sounds odd with the first exercise solution. Are you sure the solution didn't say "the coordinate directions are not the principal _directions_"?

Comment: The exercise I am talking about can be found if you google the following:Assume the Gauss map composed with the coordinate chart is given by  This should bring you to a past paper and the question 1c of this past paper

Comment: Did you find it?

Comment: My oops: When I typed "second fundamental form" earlier my brain was thinking "shape operator". I'll type up an answer shortly....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $S$ be a regular surface, $f$ a local parametrization in some neighborhood of a point $p$, and $f_{x}$, $f_{y}$ the coordinate vector fields, and $N$ a continuous unit normal field. Notation below follows the [exam](http://www2.imperial.ac.uk/~aneves/papers2/exam12.pdf) mentioned in the comments.

The *first fundamental form* is the quadratic form on $T_{p}S$ whose matrix with respect to the basis $\{f_{x}, f_{y}\}$ is
$$
I = \left[\begin{array}{@{}cc@{}}
    f_{x} \cdot f_{x} & f_{x} \cdot f_{y} \\
    f_{x} \cdot f_{y} & f_{y} \cdot f_{y} \\
  \end{array}\right]
 = \left[\begin{array}{@{}cc@{}}
    g_{11} & g_{12} \\
    g_{12} & g_{22} \\
  \end{array}\right].
$$
The *second fundamental form* is the quadratic form on $T_{p}S$ whose matrix with respect to the basis $\{f_{x}, f_{y}\}$ is
$$
II = \left[\begin{array}{@{}cc@{}}
    N \cdot f_{xx} & N \cdot f_{xy} \\
    N \cdot f_{xy} & N \cdot f_{yy} \\
  \end{array}\right]
  = \left[\begin{array}{@{}cc@{}}
    e & f \\
    f & g \\
  \end{array}\right].
$$

The *shape operator* is the endomorphism associated to $II$ by "raising an index" with respect to $I$. Its matrix in the basis $\{f_{x}, f_{y}\}$ is
$$
\frac{1}{g_{11} g_{22} - g_{12}^{2}}\left[\begin{array}{@{}rr@{}}
     g_{22} & -g_{12} \\
    -g_{12} &  g_{11} \\
  \end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{@{}cc@{}}
    e & f \\
    f & g \\
  \end{array}\right],
$$
its eigenvalues are the principal curvatures, and its eigenvectors are the principal directions.

If the coordinate basis $\{f_{x}, f_{y}\}$ is orthonormal at $p$, then the matrix of the first fundamental form at $p$ is the identity, so the matrix of the shape operator coincides with the matrix of the second fundamental form, just as you've noticed; if the coordinate basis is not orthonormal, however, the matrices of the second fundamental form and the shape operator do not have the same entries.

Comment: Thanks a lot great answer is all clear now!

Comment: May I ask what is meant by _The shape operator is the endomorphism associated to_ $II$ _by "raising an index" with respect to_ $I$.
I am only familiar with the definition of the shape operator as the differential of the Gauß map and it being an endomorphism on the tangent space.

Great answer by the way.

Comment: @TheTralfamadorian "Greetings!" <> Here _raising an index..._ is just a fancy way of describing $I^{-1}II$, i.e., defining the shape operator $S$ by $II(u, v) = I(S(u), v)$. IIRC, this a special case of the [musical isomorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_isomorphism).

Comment: Thankyou! It's all clear now.